# Array going None during recursion

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I was trying to match each element of `matches[0]` to each element of `matches[1]` and get the output finally which element matched with which. But during the recursion the variable `path` become `None`.

**Functions**

```
def improve(ncipher,x): #probably do not have any problem
    for i in x:
        try:
            if x[i]!=ncipher[i]:
                return 0
        except:
            ncipher[i]=x[i]
    return ncipher
def find_indexes(matches,cipher,path):  #the function causing problems
    print 'matches=',matches,'cipher=',cipher,'path=',path,'\n'
    if len(matches)==0:
        return [(0)]
    for x in matches[0]:
        print 'x=',x,'path=',path
        cipher=improve(cipher,x[1])
        if cipher==0:
            return [(0)]
        path=find_indexes(matches[1:],cipher,path)
        if path==[(0)]:
            return [(0)]
        else:
            print 'path=',path
            return path.append((x))
```

**Output**

```
matches= [[['season', {'1': 's', '3': 'a', '2': 'e', '5': 'n', '4': 'o'}]], [['month', {'8': 'h', '5': 'n', '4': 'o', '7': 't', '6': 'm'}]]] cipher= {} path= [0] 

x= ['season', {'1': 's', '3': 'a', '2': 'e', '5': 'n', '4': 'o'}] path= [0]
matches= [[['month', {'8': 'h', '5': 'n', '4': 'o', '7': 't', '6': 'm'}]]] cipher= {'1': 's', '3': 'a', '2': 'e', '5': 'n', '4': 'o'} path= [0] 

x= ['month', {'8': 'h', '5': 'n', '4': 'o', '7': 't', '6': 'm'}] path= [0]
matches= [] cipher= {'1': 's', '3': 'a', '2': 'e', '5': 'n', '4': 'o', '7': 't', '6': 'm', '8': 'h'} path= [0] 

path= [0]
path= None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\timepass\py\interviewstreet\fb_cipher.py", line 115, in <module>
    find_match(message,words)
  File "E:\timepass\py\interviewstreet\fb_cipher.py", line 67, in find_match
    sol_indexes=find_indexes(matches,{},[0])
  File "E:\timepass\py\interviewstreet\fb_cipher.py", line 24, in find_indexes
    return path.append((x))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

**Questions**

1. Why does `path` become `None` during the recursions?
2. How do I overcome this and store the elements matching with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return path.append((x))` edits `path` in place and returns `None`. If you want to return the new value of `path`, split it into two lines.

```
path.append((x)) 
return path
```

Comment: By Python convention, whenever a method *modifies* an object, the method returns `None`. This is to make *absolutely clear* that the *original* object is modified, vs returning a *new* object and leaving the original untouched. The `sort` functions do the same.

Comment: Why `(x)`? Just looking at it, I'm not sure if you really mean `x` or `(x,)` and that'd be written as `.extend()`

Comment: just realized didn't need `(x)`

Comment: @JonClements: That is copied directly from the question. Down voter: why?

Comment: @Tim my apologies - wasn't implying you didn't know the difference - downvote not from me tho'

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the last line in your code.

`list.append()` returns `None`.

Change it to:

```
path.append(x)
return path
```

or

```
return path + [x]
```